# Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, deployment, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a rails 3.2 ruby 1.9.3 app to digital ocean.
after doing `cap deploy:setup`, `cap deploy:check`, `cap deploy`, I get the following error:

```
$ gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter
  * ←[33mexecuting "cd -- /home/deployer/apps/csd3/releases/20130724142600 && RA
ILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"←[0m
    servers: ["192.241.141.56"]
    [192.241.141.56] executing command
 ** [out :: 192.241.141.56] rake aborted! 
 ** [out :: 192.241.141.56] Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install
activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfil
e.)
```

I run gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter on the server and it completes. However, when I do cap deploy, i get the same message. I found that problem may be in the database.yml file but it seems fine.

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test: 
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: chodae_database
  host: 192.241.141.56
  pool: 5
  username: chodae
  password:
```

And Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets', '1.0.2'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'thin', '1.5.0'
  gem 'better_errors', '0.7.0'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', '0.7.1'
  gem 'meta_request', '0.2.2'
  gem 'wirble', '0.1.3'
  gem 'hirb', '0.7.1'
  gem 'populator3', '0.2.7'
  gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
  gem 'localtunnel'
  gem 'capistrano'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'pg_search', '0.6.2'
  gem "nginx", '0.0.2'
  gem "passenger", "~> 4.0.10"
end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try doing `brew install postgresql`?

Comment: I am running on windows developing environment

Answer (score 2):

First of all best practice is to use same DB for all environments.
Could you please run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec gem install pg` on server?

The problem seems to be in absence of pg gem in assets group when running

```
RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec gem install pg
this gives me Could not locate Gemfile
on the server

Comment: The problem seems to be in absence of pg gem in assets group when running

What do you mean by that?

Comment: I've provided the string below in which you can see `RAILS_GROUPS=assets`.